# Ajax Form Sent with Mootools with different versions of Sending

Tags: ajax, forms, mootools

I tried ajax form submitting with mootools. I tried 3 different ways. One worked but others failed.

This is my Html Form

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="json.php" method="post">
            <div class="fields">
                <input id="first_name" type="text" name="fname" value="" />
                <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="fields">
                <input type="text" id="last_name" name="lname" value="" />
                <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            </div>

        <input id='submitButton' type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
    <div id='bar' style='margin-top:20px'>  Yikes! </div>
</div>
```

These are the ways I tried -

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
                // This WORKED well
        $('myForm').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //new Event(e).stop();
        this.send();
        });

//This DOESNT WORK, Console error - ReferenceError: Form is not defined
        var trigger = $('submitButton');
        trigger.addEvent( 'click', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault()
          var sendform =    new Form.Request('myForm',console.log(), {
              onSend: function(){
                  console.log('sending');
              },
              onComplete: function(){
                  console.log('sent');
              }
          });           
          sendform.send();
    });
})
//This ALSO DOESNT WORK,shows-"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/basicdemos/%5Bobject%20Object%5D"
    var log = $('bar').empty()
    $('myForm').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
    new Event(e).stop();
    this.send({
        update: log,
        onComplete: function() {
            log.set('html',"SENT");
        }
    });
});
```

I think my problem maybe a little here m there, theres very little something missing.BTW, **my html form and the javascript is in the same index.php file**.

**UPDATE - this also worked -**

```
$('myForm').set('send', {
                        url: 'json.php',
                        method: 'post',
                        noCache: true,
                        onSuccess: function(){
                            console.log(this.response.text);
                        }
                    });
            $('submitButton').addEvent( 'click', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('myForm').send();
                    });
```

Comment: What version of Mootools are you using?

Comment: But in your updated version you have a file called `json.php` and a `index.php` where you say you have the form. Can you make more clear which is which. Do you have 1 or 2 different files?

Comment: Uppss I m sorry, I guess I misunderstood u.The file I m sending the data/ajax request is json.php-a different file, which returns some json data. The form and Ajax calling script are in d the same file.

Comment: Do you have the More library also loaded?

Comment: What is more lib bro? I have MOOTOOLS lib included well, as I said some method above are working well.

Comment: Mootools has the Core library, and the More library. The __[Form.Request](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Request)__ you are using is in the More library. So if you don't have it that is one reason for it not working. That is why I asked.

Comment: I included only this - mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat-yc.js. I dont know if it includes everything. and why are some other methods working.I still have a question.Is $('myForm').addEvent(....this.send() IS EQUAL to new Form.Request().send(). I mean will I get Form.Request().send() method in a mootool form by default ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45003/discussion-between-tanvir-and-sergio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that:

**First example** works because mootools has a method [**.send()**](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Request/Request.js#L146) which actually [**triggers a request**](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Request/Request.js#L212) when applied on a form element.

**Second example** fails because it needs the More library.

**Third example** has a deprecated code `new Event(e).stop();` should be `e.stop();` and I don't think you can pass `onComplete` inside the `.send()`, I tried it and [**didn't work**](http://jsfiddle.net/9uPdj/).

**Fourth example** works because you `set()` the request options before you send it. I would though recommend using `var myRequest = new Request()` syntax, and then `myRequest .send();`

---

The standard syntax for Mootools Ajax/Request is:

```
var myRequest = new Request({
    url: 'fileName.php', // here or in the form html tag "action="fileName.php"
    method: 'get',       //or post
    onRequest: function(){
        myElement.set('text', 'loading...');
    },
    onSuccess: function(responseText){
        myElement.set('text', responseText);
    },
    onFailure: function(){
        myElement.set('text', 'Sorry, your request failed :(');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank u very much bro
1.IS First example using the method of Request>send(),I guess so.I was wondering how come FORM object triggers that without having Request object
2.Second one worked after I included mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js
3.IS "e.stop()" equal to e.preventDefault().USING onComplete inside send,I found it here- http://demos111.mootools.net/Ajax.Form, .But they both are the methods of Request object,then how come one inside the other,I agree with u..
4.Using the same request repeatedly is recommended,I agree
Lastly, is there anyway I can send all Form data as json/array.

Comment: @Tanvir, you could use `$('myform').toQueryString().parseQueryString();` in the `data:` option of the request.

Comment: Thanx bro, I already found dat but one downside is it requires mootools-more.js but thats ok, One more advice I need, do u think using JSON data is better in ajax request or html,
Thank u again

Comment: wow thats cool, how do u people get such idea..Thank u very much